# Unable to connect to remote host from Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

i am trying to connect to a remove Mongo server from Mongo shell but when i run the mongo shell it keeps connecting to the localhost by default, if i enter `exit` to connect to another mongo server, the shell closes

i tried changing the `mongod.cfg` file and set the remote server ip and port but it did not work

i tried to connect to the remote server from the windows CMD but i keep getting this error `SASL mechanism 'PLAIN' is not supported`

how can i change the default connection of the mongo shell to connect to the remote mongo server?

[image]

Comment: what is the command you are running ?
Looks like SASL authentication is enabled in your remote Server.
Please post the cmd's you have tried.
See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ldap-sasl-activedirectory/index.html

Comment: @Lucia yes it is enabled `mongo host:port/db -u 'username' -p 'password' --authenticationMechanism 'PLAIN' --authenticationDatabase '$external'`

Comment: Hi , first stop the local mongo server, and then run mongo cmd to connect to remote server, that way you will atleast get what is the error while connecting.

Answer (score 0):

mongod.cfg is for your local mongo server. Changes in this file have no effect on the client/shell.

The authenticationMechanism parameter in your command should agree with remote server configuration and authenticationDatabase should be the one where the user is registered on the remote server.

There are good chances authenticationMechanism is [default SCRAM](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms/) and the database is "admin".

Try `mongo -u 'username' -p 'password' --authenticationDatabase admin host:port/db`